# how to Change the background color of outlook calendar

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to create a new Calendar in outlook programmatically and assign color to it, is that possible with vsto or not ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use any low-level property viewer tool such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy for taking a look at the associated content of the calendar folder. Do you see any hidden items there with any colors properties set?